# Is the Committee Draft of Standard C++14 public?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

[As of last Saturday...](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/04/trip-report-iso-c-spring-2013-meeting)

> This afternoon in Bristol, UK, the ISO C++ standards committee adopted
>   generic lambdas, dynamic arrays (an improved version of C99 VLAs),
>   variable templates, reader/writer locks, make_unique, optional,
>   standard library user-defined literals, and a number of other language
>   and library improvements – and approved the result as the
>   feature-complete Committee Draft (CD) of Standard C++14 to be
>   distributed for its primary international review ballot.

I'm interested reading the specifics about the new features but I can't seem to find any more written about them than is in the link above.

Comment: "Updated papers for these and other features, as well as an updated working draft, are expected to be available in the next two or three weeks." From [here](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/04/trip-report-iso-c-spring-2013-meeting)

Comment: C++11 itself is giving me hard time to learn, and now they want to come up with C++14! Give some breathing space to compiler vendors and programmers. Thought that next std will take at least 5 years.

Comment: @iammilind It looks quite small and incremental compared to C++11. I wonder if they added standalone `cbegin` and `cend` functions.

Comment: @iammilind They say it's primarily a bug fix release, so it's good that they release it before most of compilers' writers actually implemented C++11

Comment: @piokuc, But Clang fully supports C++11 now :D A fully C++11-conforming compiler should be available this summer :)

Comment: @chris that's lovely, but people often have to write portable code, and so relying on features available in one, leading compiler is not an option for them. For example I have to make sure the stuff I write works on AIX, so compiles with IBM XL C++...

Comment: @piokuc, I know, I'm just saying we're starting to get there. Hopefully others will follow. I do think the smaller release is a bit necessary for them to catch up.

Comment: Why is SO insisting on `c++1y` when the committee itself says C++14? Seems authoritative enough.

Comment: @Dave, yes [LWG DR 2128](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3688.html#2128) was adopted into the WP

Comment: @chris, G++ 4.8.1 fully supports C++11 too and should be out this week :-P (the library isn't complete yet though, I'm working on it!)

Comment: @JonathanWakely, Thanks for the encouragement. I appreciate the work being done on GCC, and I was just looking yesterday to see "Okay, 1.5 weeks ago, it was estimated at two weeks, and now the RC is estimated a week before the release..."

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's not that we have some difficulty about what the Standard will be named, it's that we're using `c++1y` as shorthand for "C++14 draft standard".  Witness 802.11 device non-compatibility for the confusion that results if one doesn't distinguish draft compliance from the real Standard.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Updated papers for these and other features, as well as an updated
>   working draft, are expected to be available in the next two or three
>   weeks.

From [here](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/04/trip-report-iso-c-spring-2013-meeting).

[This is, also, an interesting article](http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/the-bristol-papers-the-state-of-c.html)

WG21 papers list(2013): [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/#mailing2013-03)

Std proposals Google group: [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-proposals)

**Update - 1 :**

C++14 Committee Draft (CD) announcement: [here](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/05/c14-committee-draft-cd-published-at-isocpp.org)

C++14 Committee Draft (CD), document: [here](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf)

**Update - 2 :**

C++14 Working Draft , document: [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)

*Note :* The difference between the Working Draft and the Standard can be found [here](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard)

Comment: Is there any link for the "Networking library" mentioned in the isocpp blog?

Comment: @mfontanini, have a look [here](http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/blog.html), part I through part IV, there are 3 or for 4 papers that can be included in the Networking library paper. You can join the [std-proposals google group](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-proposals).

Comment: Oh, I'd read the ip address and byte order conversion proposals. I just thought the network proposal was somehow "bigger". Thanks, +1 from me!

Comment: It's been three weeks.  Do you have any idea where the updates might be found?

Comment: @BenVoigt, [this](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/05/post-bristol-standards-papers-mailing-available), and a couple of other articles, for news watch isocpp.org

Comment: @BenVoigt, news [here](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/05/c14-committee-draft-cd-published-at-isocpp.org)

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure that this is the *official* draft, but it seems so: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft

Comment: That link doesn't contain the draft the OP wants, as far as I can tell.

Comment: That is the home of the document source, but there will probably be some more changes committed now that the meeting is over.

Comment: There is a "2013 Post-Bristol" milestone in this gihub repo with a few open issues: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues?milestone=1&state=open