# list of standard concepts?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

From what I remember C++ has concepts such as Mergable, Container, Comparable, Sortable, Arithmetic etc. I seen them here and there but I never seen a list. Where can I find a list of standard C++ concepts?

-edit- people are confused but what I mean is the example template line in [this slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KufS6.png) which has Container and Sortable. What else is there?

Comment: Please clarify your question. `Mergeable` and `Sortable` are part of Concepts Lite which hasn't made it to the standard yet (so the c++1y tag is appropriate) and they are explicitly mentioned in your question. Are you referring to Concepts Lite? Or do you mean type requirements, as we already had them in C++03?

Comment: Please clarify your question. `Container` and `Comparable` are part of the type requirements defined in the C++03 standard and they are explicitly mentioned in your question. Are you referring to *type requirements*? Or do you mean concepts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where can I find a list of standard C++ concepts?

Apparently, there isn't any, it didn't make it to the standard yet; see also [Is the Committee Draft of Standard C++14 public?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16149212/341970) Nevertheless, the relevant documents seem to be [Concepts Lite: Constraining Templates with Predicates (N3580)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf) and [A Concept Design for the STL (N3351)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3351.pdf). The list, as of Jun 15, 2014, taken from N3580:

**Type Traits**

- Equality_comparable
- Totally_ordered
- Movable
- Copyable
- Semiregular
- Regular
- Function
- Regular_function
- Predicate
- Relation

**Iterator Concepts**

- Iterator_category
- Value_type
- Difference_type
- Readable
- Writable
- Permutable
- Mutable
- Advanceable
- Incrementable
- Input_iterator
- Output_iterator
- Forward_iterator
- Bidirectional_iterator
- Random_access_itertor

**Algorithm Constraints**

- Indirectly_movable
- Indirectly_copyable
- Indirectly_swappable
- Indirectly_equal
- Indirectly_ordered
- Indirectly_comparable
- Sortable
- Mergeable

Comment: I think he really means [type requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept), which were there even in C++03. For example: Neither `Comparable`, nor `Container` are on your list, although they are in the question. I believe your list is not the one the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Jefffrey OK, we cannot resolve this. He should revise his question.

Comment: @Jefffrey Oh, I see you also asked for clarification. :)

Comment: IMHO it doesn't really matter. I think both of our lists are somehow related to the question and therefore useful to future views.

Comment: Ali got it right. See my edit if you want to see the slide I got the question from @Jefffrey

Comment: @acidzombie24 Thanks. I saw that Stroustrup presentation yesterday. :)

Comment: @Jefffrey As this confusion shows, Jefffrey's  answer can also be useful for future visitors.

Comment: It was pretty good wasn't it!? Where is your list from I don't see some of these in either n3580 (nor n3351, for example the word Advanceable is in neither). I don't know what the difference between Writable and Mutable or what is Semiregular and regular

Comment: @acidzombie24 `Advanceable` is on page 34. It used to be `WeaklyIncrementable`. Everything on my list should be in N3580.

Comment: @Ali: Odd, I was using firefox to search the PDF. It didn't before but now it does. I'm extremely confused because it isn't like I updated since then

Answer (score 9):

> From what I remember C++ has concepts such as Mergable, Container, Comparable, Sortable, Arithmetic etc. I seen them here and there but I never seen a list. Where can I find a list of standard C++ concepts?

### What are concepts

Concepts are a term that refer to the formalization of type requirements that must be enforced by the compiler. [This draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf) (N3580) contains all the details.

### What are *type requirements*

Type requirements are a set of requirements, defined even in the C++03 standard, that must be enforced by the programmer in order to apply some operations on said type. The standard never call them *concepts*.

### List of type requirements

I think you mean *type requirements* given that:

- you mentioned `Container`
- you mentioned `Comparable`
- the fact that you *remember* C++ has "concepts"

So, here's the list of type requirements in which you can also find `Container` and `Compare` (as organized by [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept)):

#### Basic

- DefaultConstructible
- MoveConstructible
- CopyConstructible
- MoveAssignable
- CopyAssignable
- Destructible

#### Layout

- TriviallyCopyable
- TrivialType
- StandardLayoutType
- PODType

#### Library-wide

- EqualityComparable
- LessThanComparable
- Swappable
- ValueSwappable
- NullablePointer
- Hash
- Allocator
- FunctionObject
- Callable
- Predicate
- BinaryPredicate
- Compare

#### Container

- Container
- ReversibleContainer
- AllocatorAwareContainer
- SequenceContainer
- AssociativeContainer
- UnorderedAssociativeContainer

#### Container element

- CopyInsertable
- MoveInsertable
- EmplaceConstructible

#### Iterator

- Iterator
- InputIterator
- OutputIterator
- ForwardIterator
- BidirectionalIterator
- RandomAccessIterator

#### Stream I/O functions

- UnformattedInputFunction
- FormattedInputFunction
- UnformattedOutputFunction
- FormattedOutputFunction

#### Random Number Generator

- SeedSequence
- UniformRandomNumberGenerator
- RandomNumberEngine
- RandomNumberEngineAdaptor
- RandomNumberDistribution

#### Concurrency

- BasicLockable
- Lockable
- TimedLockable
- Mutex
- TimedMutex
- SharedTimedMutex

#### Other

- UnaryTypeTrait
- BinaryTypeTrait
- TransformationTrait
- Clock
- TrivialClock
- CharTraits
- pos_type
- off_type
- BitmaskType
- LiteralType

Comment: I think he really means [Concepts Lite](http://concepts.axiomatics.org/~ans/) which hasn't made it to the standard yet. For example: Neither `Sortable`, nor `Mergeable` is on your list, although they are in the question. I believe your list is not the one the OP is looking for.

Comment: Hmm. I don't *think* he means type requirements. He tagged his question C++1y and mentions `Sortable` and `Mergeable`. I *think* he is referring to Concepts Lite. I asked him for clarification.

Comment: Interesting, maybe I meant both of your answer. See the slide my edit cc @Ali

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, a "**concept** is a set of requirements consisting of valid expressions, associated types, invariants, and complexity guarantees. A type that satisfies the requirements is said to **model** the concept. A concept can extend the requirements of another concept, which is called **refinement**."

Source: http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#concept

There are several concepts lists available:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept
  // to my knowledge this one is most complete
- https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html
  // note: this is pre-standard, but the descriptions are informative and also apply to the concepts existing today
- http://www.generic-programming.org/languages/conceptcpp/concept_web.php

For further explanation, see "Concepts and Modeling" as well as "Refinement" in the following:
https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_introduction.html

See also:

- https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/doc_introduction.html
- http://www.generic-programming.org/about/intro/concepts.php
- http://www.generic-programming.org/languages/conceptcpp/specification/

You may also be interested in:

- The Boost Concept Check Library (BCCL):
  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm
- New Iterator Concepts: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/iterator/doc/new-iter-concepts.html