# Named Requirements/Standard concepts availability

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

Is it possible to access/use any of the Standard concepts([list of standard concepts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228648/list-of-standard-concepts)) or [Named Requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req) on existing set of compilers?

While I am able to access concepts support in gcc using `-fconcepts -Dconcept="concept bool"`, I'm unable to use any of the named requirements. I've tried `TriviallyCopyable` which is marked as supported since C++11 on the CPP Reference page.

[Example Snippet](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/089d6a2983c8207b)

Comment: A named requirement isn't a concept, it is just the name of what the thing requires.

Comment: If someone feels it should be closed, it would be nice to drop a comment why. That'll also help me rephrase the question/judge my questions better before posting

Comment: @NathanOliver but arent named requirements written and used following the concepts syntax, `template <typename T> requires <insert concept/NamedRequirement>` here? On the CPPRef page its mentioned `Some of these requirements are being formalized in C++20 using the concepts language feature.`

Comment: It's the first thing you try when you start using requires/concept. You want a `DefaultConstructible` but you have to define `template<class  T> concept DefaultConstructible = std::is_default_constructible_v<T>` first. They're just as obvious as `inline constexpr auto T_v = T::value`, so we definitely need something like `concept T_c = T_v`.

Comment: Relevant: stackoverflow.com/q/69319153 on named requirements vs. concepts.